# Can i Insert an NVME SSD Without NVME Stand And with fans Next to it?

Tags: ssd

I have a question (I guess you already know it Since you have read the title).

My Specsheet

- Some AMD Threadripper (12 Cores & 24 threads)
- RTX 2080
- One Samsung SSD
- Seagate Firecuda or Baracuda SSHD
- ASUS ROG STRIX X399-E GAMING

The SSD I want to insert is a Crucial SSD. My Mainboard for some reason didn't come with an NVME Stand or any way to seat the SSD (Or i lost it, IDK.) I have a Noctua Fan Blasting at It and One More Fan Right next to it. (I Guess This is normal). I am a bit worried that my build is going to get destroyed (And i won't get a build in the near future).

Comment: You need an M.2 slot or add an M.2 expansion card.

Comment: I already have an M.2 Slot

Comment: So then you should be able to add the NVMe SSD.

Comment: Yes, but i am a bit worried, cus I have fans blasting at it, would it be ok?

Comment: I cannot tell you about the fans. I have a large NVMe SSD on this computer and it runs cool already.

Comment: Oh, ok i am worried if the SSD falls Down and destroys my PC

Comment: I do not use chat. Sorry. No value to me so far as I can see.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help